# Unable to switch to a different user using become_user

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am writing Ansible playbook to create key-based ssh access on several hosts with a particular user.
I have following servers:

1. automation_host
2. Master
3. Slave1
4. Slave2

From automation host I will trigger Ansible to run the playbook which should first login to master with user1, then switch to user2, create ssh keys with user2 and copy the id_rsa.pub to slave nodes.

Inventory file contents:

```
[master]
172.xxx.xxx.xxx
[slaves]
172.xxx.xxx.xxx
172.xxx.xxx.xxx
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_user=user1
```

playbook.yml file:

```
- hosts: master
  become_user: user2
  become: yes
  roles:
     - name: passwordless-ssh
```

User2 is available on all hosts (except automation_host) and is added in `sudoers` as well.

In the passwordless-ssh role, I have added the lines included below to check which user is currently executing the tasks.

```
- name: get the username running the deploy
  local_action: command whoami
  register: username_on_the_host

- debug: var=username_on_the_host
```

Debug message shows user1 ( I am expecting it to be user2)
ansible version: 2.5.2

I am very new to Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local_action` will [run on automation_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#id10), change it to `command`

```
- hosts: master
  become_user: user2
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: get the username running the deploy
    command: whoami
    register: username_on_the_host

  - debug: var=username_on_the_host['stdout']

  - name: do something
    command: echo 'hello'
    when: username_on_the_host['stdout'] == 'user2'
  - name: do something else
    command: echo 'goodby'
    when: username_on_the_host['stdout'] == 'user1'
```

Output

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************
ok: [master] => {
    "username_on_the_host['stdout']": "user2"
}

TASK [do something] *********************************************
changed: [master]

TASK [do something else] *********************************************
```

`do something else` does not run.

Comment: Thanks Michael for help :) I had earlier tried this but I was getting "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user".I  added allow_world_readable_tmpfiles=true in ansible.cfg to resolve temp file permission issue. After that I was able to switch to user2.Again Thanks for your help :)